# Know which menu resource is inflated

Tags: android, android-menu, android-inflate

Im my application I inflate different menu resources, like this:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    _menu = menu;
    if (/* CONDITION */) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_activity_detail, _menu);
    } else {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_empty, _menu);
    }
    return true;
}
```

before this I save the `Menu` object for further reuse, like inflating a new menu under specific circumstances.

Now the **question**: is there any way to know which resource I've inflated at the creation of my activity, without manually saving the id of `R.menu.menu_res`?

Comment: What do you need it for? For the menu item clicks?

Comment: In some other method I need to change the menu, but I don't want to clear and inflate the same menu everytime. NowI do `_menu.clear(); getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_activity_detail, _menu);`, but most of the times the menu inflated is always the same. I would like to avoid this.

Comment: You should not keep a reference to the menu. Why don't you use the invalidateOptionsMenu() method of your Activity? There's the supportInvalidateOptionsMenu() to handle AppCompatActivity

Comment: @MimmoGrottoli thanks for the solution! you should post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not keep a reference to the menu. Why don't you use the invalidateOptionsMenu() method of your Activity? There's the supportInvalidateOptionsMenu() to handle AppCompatActivity